# How to prevent background command going to suspend immediately

Tags: bash, ssh, jobs

Imagine this script (do not consider auth and other stuff, all SSH commands run just fine without `&`)

```
(ssh foo.com "/bin/sleep 5 && echo 1") &
(ssh bar.com "/bin/sleep 5 && echo 1") &
wait
echo "My commands finished"
```

Now, I would expect all my SSH commands to run immediately as background jobs and then, when finished, I would get the final "My commands finished" message.

But that's not what happens...

What actually happens is this

```
[1] 16155
[1]  + 16155 suspended (tty input)  ssh foo.com "/bin/sleep 5 && echo 1"
[2] 16156
[2]  + 16156 suspended (tty input)  ssh bar.com "/bin/sleep 5 && echo 1"
My commands finished
```

So all the background commands go immediatelly to `suspended` state where they stay forever. Sure I can bring them back with `fg` or `kill -CONT PID` but that's all sequential. I need to run all my commands in parallel and just wait for all of them to finish.

Do you know why is that and how to avoid the `suspended` state?

Comment: They are waiting on terminal input. Perhaps you need to enter credentials.

Comment: @n.m. no they are not, auth is done with certificates, the same command runs perfectly fine when not using `&`

Comment: Try `ssh < /dev/null ...`

Comment: Maybe your teminal settings are wrong. Did you try with `stty -tostop` before running your background commands?

Comment: I see this as a bash/posix shell programming question and not a purely configuration/sysadmin question, therefore it seems well-suited for Stack Overflow and poorly suited for Server Fault. I have therefore voted to reopen this question.

Comment: What version of which shell are you using?  This works for me as-is using /bin/sh (dash 0.5.8-2.10) and bash 4.4.18.  Perhaps try removing the parentheses? As long as your `&` is outside your quotes, it'll be backgrounded on your client system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to `n.m.`. The solution is to pass `< /dev/null` to stdin. By doing that the subprocess closes the stdin and does not block console IO as in the previous case which led to suspend state.